# How to set time to live property to a azure cosmos db item using apache spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb

How to set time to live property to a azure cosmos db item using Apache spark?

I am not able to do it using spark.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you set a default TTL? Do you need the TTL to vary per-item? If you don't, then you should follow the instructions for setting a default TTL as explained in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live

Comment: I want to set time to live property for each item.I am writing spark dataframe data to azure cosmos db container. Is there any way i can set this time to live property using apache spark while writing this data to azure cosmos db.